# Image Uploading But its Different from All other in Angular

Tags: angular6

image is not showing in my application after uploading but it showing if i made any changes in angular application.
[image]
Error in console

but there is file in respective location but it didn't show until any change in angular application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically in angular you can load dynamic image by this way.

```
<img [src]="yourImagePath" />
```

Path should be like this.

```
assets/posts/image.png
```

First try to print image name in `for` loop and check path is correct or not.

Second thing I suggest you to use `ng-template` feature of angular. This is the one of the most powerful feature of **angular**. This is mostly used to show Or load dynamic content in web page.

**Note: Make sure that space should not exist in image path.**

If sill you are not able to load or access your image then you can try this also.

**1)** You should try to load image from angular's app path instead if assets path.

```
[src]="app/path/assets/posts/image.png"     // Make path as per your structure.
```

**2)** Another option :

```
[src]="./assets/posts/image.png">
```

**Update**

The thing is, when you are running ng serve that triggered in memory webpack dev server - not a thing you want to run on your server, that is for dev only. This way, until you restarted ng serve, you wont get any changes happend in your assets folder as it is default folder for your static assets configured in .angular-cli.json.

So when you access `assets` folder dynamic, It's not possible you have to restart the app.

Solution :

I suggest you to use another location to access your dynamic images.

For an instance: You can upload a new images at...

```
public/images
```

Comment: After restarting the angular server it works fine. and one more point "/assets/posts" are belongs to Angular project folder.

Comment: <li *ngFor='let post of posts; let i = index'>
      <img [src]="post.location" width="500px" height="500px">
      <div class="likesandcomments">
        <p (click)="doLike(post._id, i)">Like <span>{{post.noOflikes}}</span></p>
        <p>Comment</p>
        <p>Share</p>
      </div>
    </li>

Comment: i know the problem, but i don't know the solution. the problem is angular loads files which are compiled, but in my case the image which i upload is not compiled, that's why it is showing after restarting the angular server.

Comment: how to show images dynamically from assets folder in angular 6

Comment: @Mahesh I have update my answer. Please check it. :)

Comment: My question is  i have to show the image which is dynamically added to the assets/posts folder without restarting the angular server, and i get  the image path from mongodb.

Comment: how to load images from outside of assets folder in Angular

Comment: @Mahesh I suggest you to upload on s3 and make folder publicand just put the path of s3. I have seen you are facing this issue from long time. So please do this. And go ahead. Happy coding :)